# Is format ####0.000000 different to 0.000000?

Tags: vb.net, string-formatting

I am working on some legacy code at the moment and have come across the following:

```
FooString = String.Format("{0:####0.000000}", FooDouble)
```

My question is, is the format string here, `####0.000000` any different from simply `0.000000`?

I'm trying to generalize the return type of the function that sets `FooDouble` and so checking to make sure I don't break existing functionality hence trying to work out what the `#` add to it here.

I've run a couple tests in a toy program and couldn't see how the result was any different but maybe there's something I'm missing?

Comment: Because you use one `0` before decimal separator - both format should return same result

Comment: @Fabio Thank you!

Comment: @Fabio If you'd like to make that an answer maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From MSDN

> The "#" custom format specifier serves as a digit-placeholder symbol.
> If the value that is being formatted has a digit in the position where
> the "#" symbol appears in the format string, that digit is copied to
> the result string. Otherwise, nothing is stored in that position in
> the result string.
>
> **Note that this specifier never displays a zero that
> is not a significant digit**, even if zero is the only digit in the
> string. It will display zero only if it is a significant digit in the
> number that is being displayed.

Because you use one 0 before decimal separator `0.0` - both formats should return same result.